# Cannot swipe to another app on a Mac when using RealVNC View in full screen mode

Tags: macos, mac, vnc-viewer

I'm using RealVNC View on my MacBook Air to connect to CentOS 6.4. It works perfectly
but when using RealVNC in fullscreen mode, I can not use my trackpad to swipe (3 fingers) between another full screen app.

I was trying to find solution to do full screen of vnc client and be able to swipe between full screen application of mac os x as well as working fine with trackpad

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ignore using RealVNC Client on Mac, because  no that's feature.
And Use Sharing Screen App (built-it mac os x software ) instead, working perfectly with trackpad

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I do not understand the answer. You mean that using a built-in application (in Mac OS X) instead of RealVNC resolves the problem? What is the exact name of the application? "Sharing Screen"?

Comment: yes it's "sharing screen" on mac